# ODI remove auto lock when object / datastore is opened

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-12c, etl

I was being stupid and enabled automatically lock object during edit / opened when I was asked the first time.

Now I want to remove the automatically lock from GUI but I couldn't seem to find it.
I googled with such topics

https://www.appservgrid.com/documentation111/docs/fmw11g1114documentation/integrate.1111/e12643/appendix_b.htm

https://odielt.wordpress.com/tag/odi-studio-settings/

So I searched `userpref.xml` inside the hard drive, I do find one `userpref.xml`.

I opened the file and inside it's just

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<UserPreferences xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/odi/userprefs UserPref.xsd"
                 xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/odi/userprefs">
  <Preference>
    <AcessibilitySetting>
      <Screenreader>false</Screenreader>
      <HighContrast>false</HighContrast>
      <LargeFonts>false</LargeFonts>
    </AcessibilitySetting>
    <UserName>None</UserName>
    <Repository>
      <Name>None</Name>
      <GUID>None</GUID>
    </Repository>
  </Preference>
</UserPreferences>
```

What can I do to make it not locking up anymore each time I open an object?  If it can be done through GUI then it's perfect if not, what should I do inside the XML file?

Thanks in advance for any help and advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to disable it.
For my, I need to go into this path.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\odi\oracledi\
```

The file need to find is actually called `userpref1222.xml`. The file will be full of your users' configuration.

Search for this `DEFAULT_LOCK_ON_OPENING` and you'll see an object block looks something like this

```
<Object class="com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpUserParam">
    <Field name="Key" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[DEFAULT_LOCK_ON_OPENING]]></Field>
    <Field name="Value" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[YES]]></Field>
    <Field name="Label" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[Lock object when opening]]></Field>
    <Field name="Type" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[com.sunopsis.graphical.userparam.SnpsTextFieldEditor]]></Field>
    <Field name="Help" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[Lock object when opening]]></Field>
    <Field name="Visible" type="boolean"><![CDATA[true]]></Field>
    <Field name="Updatable" type="boolean"><![CDATA[true]]></Field>
    <Field name="Position" type="int"><![CDATA[0]]></Field>
</Object>
```

change the second field name of "Value" then change YES to NO like below

```
<Field name="Value" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[NO]]></Field>
```

After changing it, save it, disconnect ODI, close ODI then reopen, reconnect.  This worked for me with two machines.